# Passing readable punctuated text through ssh commands in macOS?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, text-to-speech

I need to "say" things to people from the shell and would like to set up an alias that properly and automatically escapes punctuation marks.

I currently have an alias that's working great, except for questions, commas, etc.:

```
 tell_someone='ssh -e none username@hostname say'
```

But when I run `tell_someone "can you hear me?"`, it returns:

```
zsh:1: no matches found: me?
```

While `tell_someone "can you hear me\?"` works fine.  I'd like to make this work with and without quotes if possible, but I need it to obviously escape the punctuation.

**Can a simple alias do the job or do I need to resort to writing a script that will handle this in a more robust manner?**

NOTE: my rationale is that everyone I work with wears headphones and have multiple monitors and so it's nearly impossible to get attention so I frequently have to restore to more covert means like we used to do in computer lab in college pranks on Sun systems where we used to play audio at people... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this function instead of your alias (don't worry; it feels the same as an alias, it just handles arguments in a more flexible way):

```
tell_someone () { printf "%q" "$*" | ssh -x -e none someone@host say }
```

Adjust it as per your needs.